# How to interpret this DFT of a sequence which is symmetric

Tags: dft

The input sequence is spherical harmonic function of certain degree

```
x =

   7.0807 +      0i
  -5.4512 + 4.2999i
   1.9123 - 6.3227i
   1.2376 + 6.1254i
  -3.0466 - 5.2350i
   3.7713 + 4.8249i
  -3.7158 - 5.2318i
   2.8246 + 6.1738i
  -1.0723 - 6.9629i
  -1.0723 + 6.9629i
   2.8246 - 6.1738i
  -3.7158 + 5.2318i
   3.7713 - 4.8249i
  -3.0466 + 5.2350i
   1.2376 - 6.1254i
   1.9123 + 6.3227i
  -5.4512 - 4.2999i
```

The DFT of this sequence is using matlab `fft(x)`

```
ans =

   1.3513e-04 - 4.4409e-15i
   2.6141e-03 - 1.8750e-14i
   3.0165e-02 - 1.1988e-14i
   2.4893e-01 + 1.1687e-13i
   1.5438e+00 + 3.8696e-14i
   7.2281e+00 - 5.3949e-14i
   2.4804e+01 - 5.0596e-15i
   5.7306e+01 - 8.2250e-14i
   6.7616e+01 - 9.4266e-14i   (is this DC?)
  -5.7306e+01 + 1.0646e-13i
   2.4804e+01 - 1.7632e-14i
  -7.2281e+00 + 7.1085e-14i
   1.5438e+00 + 6.3319e-14i
  -2.4893e-01 - 8.3080e-14i
   3.0165e-02 - 2.9743e-14i
  -2.6141e-03 + 4.5250e-14i
   1.3513e-04 - 4.0521e-14i
```

How to interpret this output? I'm aware DFT of a sequence is DC,[+ve freq],[-vs freq] but this output sequence confuses me.

Comment: Could you add to your question what exactly it is that confuses you?

Comment: currently implementing an interpolator to interpolate samples on the sphere. though its just three equations I am kind of stuck which led to investigate the data.

Comment: a little related: when is center-padding of zeros and padding of zeros at both ends are preferred? I do like [DC, +ve freq, 0, 0,...,0, 0 -ve freq] for odd input sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If follows directly from the definition of the DFT (and it's inverse) that both $x[n]$ and its DFT $X[k]$ are periodic with $N$, i.e.

$$x[n] = x[n+m\cdot N], m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
X[k] = X[k+m\cdot N], m \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Your signal has a period of $N=17$ and is conjugate symmetric. Conjugate symmetry in one domain makes the other domain real, so you have $X[k] \in \mathbb{R}$. The small residual imaginary part that you are seeing in your data is just numerical noise.

For simplicity, let's assume that the sample rate is 1700Hz which makes your frequency resolution 100Hz. That means values in the DFT $X[k]$ correspond to the frequency $k \cdot 100Hz$, i.e. 0Hz, 100Hz, 200Hz, etc.
The first value in the array corresponds to DC which can you easily verify by checking

$$X[0] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]$$

Given the periodicity, the notion of "negative" frequencies is somewhat arbitrary. Let's look at $X[10]$. We can interpret this as center frequency of 1000Hz or -700Hz. Since the signal is periodic it makes mathematically no difference so it boils down to convention and/or convenience.

Comment: What about the symmetry in $X[k]$: $X[k]=X[N-1-k](-1)^k$?